# How to read shapefile in Django view helper function?

Tags: django

As part of my view logic I need to check if Latitude and Longitude points are withing city boundaries.
To do that, I am using city shapefiles with geopandas. It all works ok locally in plain python code.
However, when I run the following code in Django:

```
LA_geo_df = gpd.read_file('./City_Boundaries/City_Boundaries.shp')
```

I get the error:

```
DriverError at /
./City_Boundaries/City_Boundaries.shp: No such file or directory
```

What is the proper Django way of loading such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-generated Django settings file will have a `BASE_DIR` setting that looks like this

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

This is an absolute file path to the root of your Django app. You can use this setting to build an absolute path to your file

```
CITY_BOUNDARIES_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'City_Boundaries', 'City_Boundaries.shp')
```

Then where you want to load the file you can use the setting

```
from django.conf import settings

LA_geo_df = gpd.read_file(settings.CITY_BOUNDARIES_FILE_PATH)
```